# Email piping to a laravel app, get the senders server IP and server hostname, is that possible?

Tags: laravel, email, centos7, piping, exim

I have an email address that all email received is piped to a laravel app which then stores the headers message subject etc in a database. This works fine, but what I need to do is also get the senders server IP and server hostname, is that possible?

I am using [this tool](https://github.com/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser) to parse mail and Exim.